# Reading table html rows values to a servlet to another jsp page for editing

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to get the values for the rows which is then sent to a Java servlet then read by another page and inserts those values into the text boxes for the user to edit and write it back into the text file.

So it gets read by ProductIO which reads the textfile.
Its then entered into a jsp table

```
   <c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
                <tr>
                    <td ><c:out value='${product.code}'/></td>
                    <td ><c:out value='${product.description}'/></td>
                    <td >${product.priceCurrencyFormat}</td>
                    <td><form action="editproduct" method="post">
                            <input type="submit" value = "Edit">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td><form action="deleteproduct" method="post">
                            <input type="submit" value = "Delete">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </c:forEach>
```

The User Clicks either the delete or edit button which will then send action to either the *deleteproduct servlet* or the *editproduct servlet*(only asking about the edit for now)

The edit product servlet

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String url = "/editproduct.jsp";
    getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher(url)
            .forward(request, response);
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    if (action == null) {
        action = "editproduct";  // default action
    } else if (action.equals("editproduct")) {
        String productCode = request.getParameter("productCode");
        String descString = request.getParameter("description");

        //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Product product = (Product) session.getAttribute("cart");
        if (product == null) {
            product = new Product();
        }
        getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(url)
                .forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Which the three Values are put into three text boxes on the editProduct.jsp page(where im having a problem getting the values to insert into the text boxes for it to be written back to the text file with the new information)

```
            <form action="Product" method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">        
        <label>Code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="code" value='<%=request.getAttribute("code")%>' 
               required><br>
        <label >Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name="desc" value='<%=request.getAttribute("description")%>' 
               required ><br>
        <label >Price:</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" value='<%=request.getAttribute("price")%>'  
               required ><br>        
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <!--<input type="submit" value="Update Product" class="margin_left">-->
        <!--<input type="submit" value="View Product" class="margin_left">-->
        <button type="submit">Update</button><br>
```

I can share more code if needed.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, I'll try and help you formulate it, **which** part isn't working?

Comment: Im having a problem filling in the text field in the edit page so that the user can edit the existing data. i cant seem to get the data to write to the servlet to be read by the editProducts.jsp page

Comment: Before displaying values to textbox set values to attributes and use EL expressions to replace scriptlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't calling `request.setAttribute()` with any of the attributes in your Servlet. I assume you meant to add something like

```
request.setAttribute("code", productCode);
request.setAttribute("description", descString);
request.setAttribute("price", product.getPrice());
```

Before forwarding the request.